# Django get_absolute_url blank

Tags: django

Im using get_absolute_url method to return a slug field which will be substituted in my url.

For some reason, the value that is returned is blank,

models.py

```
class Category(models.Model):
    """ model class containing information about a category in the product catalog """
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=50, unique=True,
                            help_text='Unique value for product page URL, created automatically from name.')
    description = models.TextField()
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    meta_keywords = models.CharField(max_length=255,
                                     help_text='Comma-delimited set of SEO keywords for keywords meta tag')
    meta_description = models.CharField(max_length=255,
                                        help_text='Content for description meta tag')
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    #objects = models.Manager()
    #active = ActiveCategoryManager()

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'categories'
        ordering = ['name']
        verbose_name_plural = 'Categories'

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

    @models.permalink
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return ('catalog_category', (), { 'category_slug': self.slug })
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('catalog.views', 
        (r'^$', 'index', { 'template_name':'catalog/index.html'}, 'catalog_home'), 
        (r'^category/(?P<category_slug>[-\w]+)/$',   
            'show_category', { 'template_name':'catalog/category.html'},'catalog_category'),  
        (r'^product/(?P<product_slug>[-\w]+)/$',  
            'show_product', { 'template_name':'catalog/product.html'},'catalog_product'), 

)
```

catalog_tags.py

```
@register.inclusion_tag("tags/category_list.html") 
def category_list(request_path): 
    print 'catalog_tags-request_path', request_path
    #active_categories = Category.objects.filter(is_active=True) 
    active_categories = Category.objects.all() 
    return { 
          'active_categories': active_categories, 
          'request_path': request_path 
     }
```

catalog_list.html

```
<h3>Categories</h3> 
<ul id="categories">
{% with active_categories as cats %} 
    {% for c in cats %} 

    <li>
     {% ifequal c.get_absolute_url request_path %} 
          {{ c}}<br /> 
     {% else %} 
          <a href="{{ c.get_absolute_url }}" class="category">{{ c.name }}</a><br /> 
     {% endifequal %} 
     </li>
    {% endfor %} 
{% endwith %} 
</ul>
```

The c.get_absolute_url in the above html returns blank.

Comment: Let's first verify that the reverse is working.  Can you do this `print Category.objects.all()[0].get_absolute_url()`?

Comment: This is the error I get,TemplateSyntaxError at /
Caught NoReverseMatch while rendering: Reverse for 'catalog_category' with arguments '('category_slug',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.

Comment: Please verify that you are using @Aamir solution.

Comment: This is the new error,Caught NoReverseMatch while rendering: Reverse for 'catalog_category' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'category_slug': u'baby'}' not found.

Comment: That is simply not true. You have the right keyword args for the function.  Please verify you didn't modify your urls.py

Comment: Having the same issue.. Did you resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('catalog_category', kwargs={'category_slug': self.slug})
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you ask the user to set the slug when doing data entry or is the slug programmatically created from the name field?

The help text suggests the later, but I don't see the code? You need to override the save method:

[How to create a unique slug in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3816307/how-to-create-a-unique-slug-in-django)