# Generate unique string for each db object

Tags: django

I have a model where I need to create a **UNIQUE** string for each object in the db.

I've made a function to generate the string, but I can create an object using the django admin once, and then the second time it will error out and say that the value is not unique.

What can I do so Django just generates a new string if the previous one was used already?

models.py

```
def randomword(length):
   letters = string.ascii_lowercase
   return ''.join(random.choice(letters) for i in range(length))

class Refferal(models.Model):
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=254, unique=True)
    coupon = models.CharField(default=randomword(4), primary_key=True, editable=False, max_length=4)
    count = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

Log output from when I try to create the second object using the admin
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 607, in wrapper
    return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 130, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py", line 44, in _wrapped_view_func
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py", line 231, in inner
    return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 1638, in add_view
    return self.changeform_view(request, None, form_url, extra_context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 43, in _wrapper
    return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 130, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 1522, in changeform_view
    return self._changeform_view(request, object_id, form_url, extra_context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 1565, in _changeform_view
    self.save_model(request, new_object, form, not add)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 1081, in save_model
    obj.save()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 746, in save
    force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 784, in save_base
    force_update, using, update_fields,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 887, in _save_table
    results = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, returning_fields, raw)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 926, in _do_insert
    using=using, raw=raw,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 82, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1204, in _insert
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(returning_fields)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1384, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 68, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 77, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 86, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 86, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "index_refferal_coupon_a6e4bc31_pk"
DETAIL:  Key (coupon)=(vtgs) already exists.
```

Comment: This should help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3816307/how-to-create-a-unique-slug-in-django

Comment: Here you *call* the function, and set as `default` the *result* of that function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You here will evaluate *eagerly* the call `randomword(4)`, and set the *result* of that function call as default value. You can however pass a callable:

```
def randomword(length):
   letters = string.ascii_lowercase
   return ''.join(random.choice(letters) for i in range(length))

def random4():
    return randomword(4)

class Refferal(models.Model):
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=254, unique=True)
    coupon = models.CharField(default=random4, primary_key=True, editable=False, max_length=4)
    count = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

Note that we do *not* call the function. We only pass a reference to the function.

That being said, it might be better to use Django's [**`UUIDField`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#uuidfield). This is made to store and generate random UUIDs, which are likely better sources of random strings.

Comment: Smart linking function `random4()`, I like it. I agree with the UUIDs too.